# Django admin - creating image admin models

Tags: django, image, upload, gallery, image-gallery

I have looked through the posts but didn't find what I'm looking for, this is why I'm asking.

The goal is to be able to create image galleries in the admin, then to upload images and to choose in which (already created) gallery to be uploaded and after that, when creating a post (for example) to have a field which to access the gallery model and to choose images to be used in a carousel gallery in the said post.

For example, I'm creating a post in a travel blog and would like to add few images from the trip I had to use in a carousel.

I hope I have explained the goal understandable and someone to be able to show me a way or to point in the right direction

If there are any first party solutions, I'd be very happy

Please, since I'm new in django link a more detailed answer or tutorial or explain for a newbie

Comment: You can create `Post` model with `ForeignKey` linked to  `Trip` model, in `Trip` detail page, you could add `InlineModelAdmin` with a list of posts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if I want to reuse the same photo or image for multiple posts? The idea is to have a place (a galleries) where the photos I've uploaded and to be able to open the gallery when I create a post and to choose which images I want to use for the current post.

Answer (score 0):

Heres answer for your idea..
change your models.py like this

```
class Carousel(models.Model):
    carousel_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.carousel_name

class Photo(models.Model):
    carousel = models.ForeignKey(Carousel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image =models.ImageField(upload_to="carousel_image", height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
```

Then in your Views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .models import Carousel, Photo
class CarouselView(DetailView):
    model = Carousel
    template_name = 'carousel.html'
```

Now in your admin.py:

```
from .models import Carousel, Photo
class PhotoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model= Photo
    extra= 3

class CarouselAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[PhotoInline]
admin.site.register(Carousel, CarouselAdmin)
```

Now make your urlpattern to fetch pk as kwargs for image to be loaded like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', CarouselView.as_view())
]
```

Finally in your template:
render as:

```
 <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for photo in carousel.photo_set.all %}
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" alt="Image {{forloop.counter}}" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Now the gallery should work as you have expected it to.
Hope You get what you are searching for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I can use snippets of that for the final product. The only thing I either don't understand or can't see is is there a way or is it possible for me to create a carousel folder, i.e. Italy upload files in it. Use it in a post about Italy. Then, create a folder called Spain, the files to be uploaded in that folder and use this folder in another post or posts. Also is there a way to choose which photos to use from a certain folder

Comment: Not sure about folder but what you can do is create different carousel items and you can store different photos related to that carousel and access it using its Primary Key.